# TestFlight external users, only some receive email notification

Tags: ios, testflight

i submit app to apple for testflight beta testing.  all external users receive email notification from apple.  next day i update app and submit new version to testflight.  some of the external users receive notification, others do not.  see attached screenshot, some folks notified 8 dec, some folks 9 dec.  why isn't everybody notified 9 dec?  i used a third email address (not my apple id, not an internal tester), and i was notified 8 dec, but i was not one of the folks notified on 9 dec.  apple screen shows who was notified re most recent 9 dec version, and who only received the 8 nov version.
[image: itunes connect screenshot]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't even see some things that are being distributed from my own account

Comment: @blueether i plan to email the external users to research this, one guess... if external tester does not install a particular build, apple testflight will not send her email again when future builds are released on testflight.

Comment: Is your apple Id an email address or just a regular username? Mine is a username, which apple has been trying to get me to change for a while. I haven't been able to for some unknown server-side reason though.